# Function to print all elements of stack?

Tags: c++, stack

I want to print all the elements of a character stack. This is my function:

```
void print_stack(stack<char> c)
{
     stack<char> a = c;
     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
          std::cout<<a.top();
          a.pop();
     }
}
```

Currently, it is printing only the first `a.size() - 1` elements and not the last element. I am having trouble figuring out why this is the case.

Comment: I don't know, have you tried?

Comment: Yes, and in my program, it wasn't working correctly. I was wondering if anyone had a better way/one that is normally used.

Comment: the loop is wrong, you should iterate until a is empty

Comment: That's what it was. Thanks

Comment: a side note: if you need to introspect the contents of the stack, then perhaps use some other container, which allows to do so without making a copy

Comment: This questions shoud definitely not be tagged as `c`, this is pure `c++` !

Comment: `  while(!a.empty()){  std::cout << a.pop(); }  `

Comment: @ArifBurhan `std::stack<T>::pop` does not return anything but `void`

Comment: Then have  **cout<<a.top(); a.pop()** all in while loop, and you need an empty() method which returns true when the stack is empty.

Comment: Or   **while(( a.size() ) != 0)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loop is wrong, consider what happens to `a` when you do `a.pop()` if `a.size()` was 3, it is now 2, so your loop will iterate one less time. You should do this:

```
while (!a.empty()) {
      std::cout<<a.top();
      a.pop();
 }
```

Also you dont need to copy `c`, since your function signiture is `void print_stack(stack<char> c)` not `void print_stack(stack<char> &c)` you are creating a copy of `c` for the scope of this function anyway. Which means this would be sufficient:

```
void print_stack(stack<char> c) {
    while (!c.empty()) {
        std::cout<<c.top();
        c.pop();
    }
}
```

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/ex7DGZ)

Comment: So, if I wanted to make a function that cleared all the elements of the stack, and I want it to register with the global stack<char> c, I would use `void clear_stack(stack<char> &c)`?

Comment: @NickPredey, something like that.

Comment: Funny looking back 4 years ago and seeing to where I've progressed from this question..thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you. For some explanation for my fellow noobs: while loops continue to run infinitely until a specific condition right? So what we're doing is printing out whatever is at the top of the stack, then pop (or remove the element) and re-iterate. This keeps happening once the stack is now empty (since we kept popping). Once its empty, it stops. Done.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
```

or

```
while(a.size() > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply do

```
std::stack<int> c;
std::cout << c; //[a, b, c]
```

Though you can't format it, you'll be able to get the representation of it.